wxWidgest + Vulkan
Как использовать wxWidgest и Vulkan в Си?
Пожалуйста не надо говорить про этот сайт: https://computingonplains.wordpress.com/vulkan-with-wxwidgets/.
Этот вариант подходит только для С++

Ради любопытства пошарился в сети... А их, вообще, можно использовать с Си?

Да, они писались изначально для этого языка, Юрий Козлов

wxWidgest на си нельзя использовать, вулкан - можно

Спасибо, user7860670
